# How to pass parameters to JVM using Windows Java Control Panel: Server Tab

Tags: java, windows-server-2016

I'm trying to add arguments to the JVM using the Java Control Panel.  I am able to edit the Runtime Parameters field in the Users tab, but not the Server tab (see image).  The Find, Add, Remove buttons are greyed out.
I've tried opening the Windows Control Panel as administrator and I've gone to the JRE bin folder and ran javacpl.exe as administrator and it's the same behavior.
The java docs on the Windows Control Panel don't mention the User and Server tab:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/jcp/jcp.html

Anyone come across this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

So, as it turns out - you should use the JAVA_OPTIONS System Environment variable.  I feel silly for having posted this, but I guess that's how it goes.  I hope this helps someone in the future.

[image]